# Display Count of associated nodes as "more" in Calendar View?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I'm using the [Drupal Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module to create a monthly calendar view. As is default behavior the monthly calendar shows a list of the days events on each day. I have the Format Settings set to only display one event and then a "more" link. I would like to have the total number of events for that day next to the "more" link.

I attempted to add a "nid:count" aggregated field but it only counted for each node (so it was always "1") not per day.

How can I show the total number of events per day?

Answer (score 1):

In your calendar view you can select format>Settings: Too many items to "Hide all add link to day" and it will show the totals for that day.